# how to make logo appear through modal background

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, z-index

I am trying to do something a bit different with a modal and show our logo over the overlay at all times.

situation is, when a user opens the modal, the modal appears, but our logo then overlays just over the dark transparent portion.

Ive tried this in a number of ways and can see that the logo's z-index keeps getting reset, even if I hardcode the z-index and position of it above the modals z-index.

Ive even tried using a secondary logo image to show when the dialog is displayed so that it appears on its own above the overlay. but no luck.

is there something im missing here ?

thanks in advance

```
$("[data-toggle=modal").click(function(){
// events to occur globally for when a modal is toggled
    $("#ajax-right-modal-large").on('shown.bs.modal',function(){
      $("#logo").addClass('hidden');
       $("#logo-modal").removeClass('hidden').attr('style','border:1px solid blue; z-index: 1701 !important;');      
      $(".fade-in").css('z-index','1501');
      $("#logo-modal").attr('style','');
    });
    // end function
});
```

Comment: Post your source code with styles

Comment: Square bracket is missing in $("[data-toggle='modal']")

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you have a position set to your navbar so you are trying to position your logo when the parent has a position and that is why you are not getting any results.  It is hard telling since I cant see what your html markup looks like but I assume that is the issue.  So you can do a couple of different things here.  If you are using a static navbar you can do probably do something like:

```
body.modal-open .navbar-static-top{
  position:inherit;
}
```

And then you can position your logo to a high z-index and give it a fixed position above the modal overlay.

If you are using a fixed navbar then you may not want to do this because it will make your content jump around and your navbar will dissapear underneath the modal overlay so you may just want to add a logo at the top of your page and give it a `display:none` and then on the `body.modal-open`  Give this a display of block so it only appears when your modal is open.

Or you could just append and remove a logo evey time a modal is opened with jquery like so:

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal',function(){
  $('body').append('<a class="appended-logo">Appended Logo</a>')
});
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal',function(){
  $('.appended-logo').remove();
});
```

Here is a fiddle with just putting a logo at the top of the page with a display of none and also with the jquery appended logo so you can see both of these.

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/LjLm4pox/)

Anyway I hope this is what you are looking for and hope it helps.